# ArrayList, passing strings to fragment Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments, arraylist

I have a server, from which i get the values that i need(name, date, city, picture_url). To get them are in getValues class. I'm using Json.
All the values are saved in an ArrayList called array. I would use them in multiple classes. I would like to call the array in FragmentB. This is the code for the ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<String> array;
`array = new ArrayList<String>();
 array.add(finalresult.getString("picture"));
 array.add(finalresult.getString("name")); 
 array.add(finalresult.getString("date"));
 array.add(finalresult.getString("city"));`
```

Then i thought i needed some kind of function, so it can be called, from other classes. I wanted to name the function, then arguments are numbers, so you can select which element you want, then you just return the object you wanted.

```
public ArrayList<String> getEvent(int pos)
    {
        return array.get(pos);
    }
```

But here i get an error:

```
Required: java.util.ArrayList <java.lang.String>
Found: java.lang.String
```

In Fragment, i want the specific element of the array, and save it in one string, so i can call it later.

Something like this:

```
    public class FragmentB extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment{
        private GetEvents getEvents = new GetEvents();

        private String picture1, name1, city1, date1;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            picture1 = getEvents.getArray(0);
            name1 = getEvents.getArray(1);
            city1 = getEvents.getArray(2);
            date1 = getEvents.getArray(3);
       }
}
```

I know that this is wrong. What is the correct way to pass the elements, and then call them in the fragment?

Comment: Yes, because you have to change type of `getEvent` method from ArrayList<> to String.. like  `public String getEvent(int pos)
    {
        return array.get(pos);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error, it is just that `getEvent(int pos)` should return a `String` and not a `List<String>`.

If (name, city, date, picture) is an object of your application model (I understand that these are used in several places), you may take advantage to create a simple pojo class to hold these infos, e.g.

```
public class Event {
    String name, city, url;
    Date date;
    // +constructor
    // +getters
}
```

Then you can store, pass as parameter, filter, sort `Event`s and access properties with specific methods without ambiguity.

Actually storing values with different meaning in an array is bad practice: an array should contain objects of the same nature, e.g. a list of `Event`, a list of `city`, etc. Think of what will happen if the order in the array changes. Does it make sense to have `city` at position `0` and `name` at `1`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, will tell you how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, and it is easier to use. But I have one more problem. I need `public class FragmentB extends ActionBarActivity` . It has no errors, but when i try to call it in an adapter                     `           `case 1:
                    FragmentB b = new FragmentB();
                    return b; `, it says that i need android.support.v4.app.Fragment, which i can't implement because i need ActionBarActivity. Tried to import it, but it's not used, soo no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: If `FragmentB` extends `ListFragment` that extends `Fragment` there is no need to implement it yourself. There is not enough context. You should post another specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
  public ArrayList<String> getEvent(int pos)
{
    return array.get(pos);
}
```

to:

```
 public String getEvent(int pos)
{
    return array.get(pos);
}
```

But I think you should consider passing info to your fragments via [arguments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle))